# Passing a parameter to a bean referenced in a constructor in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, applicationcontext

I want to pass a parameter to a bean referenced from another bean in Spring Context.xml. Is it even possible ?

NOTE : The DISCARD bean would have different values when referenced from different beans.

```
<bean id="dropBadTimestampFilter" class="TimestampRangeMatcherModifier">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="_TIME"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="DISCARD" /> <!--Want to pass a prameter value to this-->
</bean>

<bean id="DISCARD" class="SettingModifier">
     <property name="fields">
         <map>
             <entry key="_ORG" value="CONSTANT"/>
             <entry key="CAUSE" value="______"/>  <!-- Want to be passed from bean referring it-->
         </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Is there a way that we could have a reference of bean using a bean using Spring Expression Language so that the following is possible :

```
<bean id="DISCARD" class="SettingModifier">
     <property name="fields">
         <map>
             <entry key="_ORG" value="CONSTANT"/>
             <entry key="CAUSE" value="#{dropBadTimestampFilter.CAUSE}"/>  <!-- Can this bean get reference of all the beans using it and not only dropBadTimestampFilter. -->
         </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: So the `DISCARD` bean will have different values in `fields` property? What is the significance of `"NOT_CONSTANT"` there?

Comment: Updated the questions to answer your questions.

Comment: Looks like cause is really a property of `dropBadTimestampFilter` and not `DISCARD` bean. Why convoluted dependencies here?  Maybe iam not understanding it correctly.

Comment: Yes the cause is a property of dropBadTimestampFilter but different filters using the SettingModifier would have different causes which they will pass to SettingModifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you've to make that bean a prototype bean, if it has different properties for different injection. And then, set the value for `"CAUSE"` key in a `@PostConstruct` method, of `TimestampRangeMatcherModifier` bean. In XML, you define such method using `init-method` attribute of `bean` tag.

Another approach would be by declaring the bean in-place, like this:

```
<bean id="dropBadTimestampFilter" class="TimestampRangeMatcherModifier">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="_TIME"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <bean class="SettingModifier"> <!-- no need of id here -->
            <property name="fields">
                <map>
                   <entry key="_ORG" value="CONSTANT"/>
                   <entry key="CAUSE" value="______"/>
               </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: I have updated my question to make use of Spring Configuration language. Is that possible ?